Markov chain transition matrix optimal solution for Prime Climb
There is a game that involves a pawn starting at the number 0 in a field from 0 to 101. Its goal is to make it to 101. With each turn, I roll two dice. I can pick one of the two dice values and either add, subtract, divide, or multiply it against the pawn's current location for the pawn's new location. After that, I must use the remaining die and do it again.
I want to figure out the optimal path or strategy to get to 101 in the fewest number of moves given any starting location on average.
My thought process was to use a transition matrix where I calculated the probability of being able to go from any start to any destination square. For example, from the square 100, there's a 38% chance it has gotten two dice rolls that allow it go make it to 101. there's also a 29% chance it has the opportunity to make it back to 100. The total probabilities for each starting square add up to more than 100% because it's the probability of being granted rolls that provide the option to go to each destination square if taken.
Then given this 101x101 transition matrix, in theory, I feel that I should be able to calculate the expected moves it takes every starting square to get to 101 if chosen optimally right? I'm lost on how this part of the calculation works. I've heard a Markov chain may be relevant or a Markov decision process, but I am not familiar.
Let me know if any areas need further clarification.

This is indeed a Markov decision process (MDP), specifically a stochastic shortest path problem. I would do some reading about those and then return to this question.
